# ng-click executing 2 methods that belongs to different controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click, angular-services

I have a controllers with name **PostController** and **CommentController** 
**PostController** having the function **showPost** 
**CommentController** having the function **showComment**
i want to execute the both the functions when button is clicked

```
<button href="#" ng-click="showPost();showComment()" class="btn">show</button>
```

how can i do that one without specifying the nested controller concept

Comment: What is the _nested controller concept_?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself?

Comment: Check out egghead's video for the "controller as" concept: http://youtu.be/tTihyXaz4Bo

Comment: we can define one controller in another controller @Davin Tryon

Comment: yahhh i tried to integrate the rails with angularjs... the function should execute at a time but it's not working... @cherniv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using service/factory. Here is simple example how it should work:

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function CommentController($scope,  myStorage) {   
    $scope.myStorage = myStorage;

    $scope.showMe = function(){
      myStorage.setIndex(3);
    }
}

function PostController($scope,  myStorage) {   
    $scope.myStorage = myStorage;    
}


myApp.factory('myStorage', function () {

       var currentBusinessIndex = 0;

       return {
            getIndex: function () {                
               return currentBusinessIndex;
            },
           setIndex: function (index) {
               currentBusinessIndex = index;               
            }
        }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="CommentController">
    <button ng-click="showMe();">press  me</button>
    <pre>{{myStorage.getIndex()}}</pre>
</div>

<div ng-controller="PostController">
    <pre>{{myStorage.getIndex()}}</pre>
</div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/1053/)**</kbd>

In addition, you can watch the service data by using `$watch`, to trigger on any data change

Comment: Thanx mate, your answer saved my day.